# Should I share a UIAlertView between classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, uialertview

I use a `UIAlertView` on my entire app warning about internet connection problem. Right now, I create a new one and show every time I need it. My app is a big app with a lot of classes and interactivity, therefore, I'm highly concerned about performance. I've seen on a few places, people creating one class with all `UIAlertViews` just to show them when needed, now, this would get my code more organized, but wouldn't really make a difference since I will have to instantiate an object of that class every time.

I have a `singleton` class already, my question is: Should I create a method on my singleton to `alloc, init` and show my `alerts`? Or even save the alert on a `property` so I don't need to instantiate a new one? If I save it to a `property`it would be on memory for the entire life of my app, right? So I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

My question is: In attention to performance and a less expensive code, what is the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to have all your alerts being made in one place, but rather than using the singleton pattern just create <del>static /</del> class methods.

Unless you are constantly throwing alerts, which you probably shouldn't, there's no benefit to keep an `UIAlertView` object in memory. The cost of allocating and initializing a `UIAlertView` object is not something you should worry about.

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer I was looking for. But, since I already have a `singleton`, can I just create methods there for the alerts or is it better to create a new class for those methods?

Comment: Sure, if you feel that those alert methods conceptually belong together with the other methods in that class.

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have static methods. The nearest equivalent to a static method in Objective-C is a C function, which would be perfectly suitable to the problem at hand.

Comment: I used the term static informally to mean the same thing as class method.

Answer (score 0):

you can write an `AlertMessenger` that does some stuff for you. but maybe your requirements are more than this example shows.

AlertMessenger.h

```
@interface AlertMessenger : NSObject

+ (void)showMissmatchAlertWithTitle:(NSString*)title;

// will be called with predefined texts from the methods above
+ (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString*)title
               withMessage:(NSString*)message
            withCancelText:(NSString*)cancelText;

@end
```

AlertMessenger.m

```
#import "AlertMessenger.h"

@implementation AlertMessenger

+ (void)showMissmatchAlertWithTitle:(NSString*)title {
    [self showAlertWithTitle:title
                 withMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"nothing_found",@"")
              withCancelText:NSLocalizedString(@"close",@"")];
}

+ (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString*)title
               withMessage:(NSString*)message
            withCancelText:(NSString*)cancelText {
    UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                   message:message
                                                  delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle:cancelText
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

@end
```

If you recognize a missmatch (in my example) you can just write:

```
[AlertMessenger showMissmatchWithTitle:@"Search"]
```

Comment: There's no need to create a class; just rewrite the class methods as C functions. Classes that are never instantiated are generally not useful in Objective-C.

Comment: What would be the benefit of rewriting them as C functions over just using class methods?